# How to extend array methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here is my  code:

```
class Array
    def anotherMap
         self.map {yield}
    end
end

print [1,2,3].anotherMap{|x| x}
```

I'm expecting to get an output of **[1,2,3]**,but I get **[nil,nil,nil]**
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Return a new array from the current array?

Comment: BTW, the `self.` is superfluous

Comment: Remember to restart your server or the new method may not be available yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Array
  def another_map(&block)
    map(&block)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code doesn't yield the value that's yielded to the block you passed to `#map`. You need to supply a block parameter and call `yield` with that parameter:

```
class Array
    def anotherMap
         self.map {|e| yield e }
    end
end

print [1,2,3].anotherMap{|x| x}
```